# Why Ubuntu is using NVIDIA Card?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, graphics, 18.10

I just installed Ubuntu(dual boot) on my MSI GS65 Stealth Thin 8RE!

There's a small light near the power button which shows the current graphics card being used. Red is NVIDIA and white is Intel.

When I use Ubuntu, it's always red and I don't know why it is happening. I tried going to Settings>Details. This shows that the graphics driver is Intel but still NVIDIA is being used.

I have not installed any NVIDIA driver and just did `nouveau.modeset=0` in GRUB!

Please help!

Comment: I doubt that light is maintained by Ubuntu and I would suggest that your problem is probably BIOS related. Maybe it is not actually testing what graph card is used but it is a setting in BIOS.

Comment: try `nvidia-smi`, you would know if the drivers are installed and the Nvidia card is in use or not. Another command to check which card is in use is `prime-select query`

Comment: Under windows if you disable nVidia device the indicator is also kept on.  I think you need correctly configure Optimus mode so nVidia card can be switched off.

Answer (score 1):

I followed "Automatic Install using standard Ubuntu Repository" from the following blog post:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-linux

I am now able to switch between NVIDIA and Intel! I currently switched to Intel, so white light is now shown.